# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'timedelta'

Tags: python, datetime

How do I do minus 30 days to the following time.

```
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") - datetime.timedelta(30)
```

The above prints the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: `strftime` returns a string, maybe you want to use it after calculating the difference?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is correct form of what you need:

```
from datetime import datetime , timedelta
(datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - timedelta(30) ).strftime("%Y-%m- 
  %dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

Do strftime after doing the date calculation

```
import datetime
(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)- datetime.timedelta(30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

As mentioned in the comments `strftime` converts a datetime to a string which is why you can't use timedelta on it.